# Переместить все элементы в созданный контейнер

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо создать контейнер и поместить все элементы, которые есть в документе в этот контейнер, используя только javascript. В интернете нашел только такую возможность сделать через jQuery, что не подходит, так как есть условие, что библиотеки использовать нельзя.

Не минусуйте без объяснений, это не решает вопроса

Мне нужно понять как сделать выборку и перемещение в контейнер

Comment: какой контейнер подойдет?

Comment: Для создания используется `document.createElement`, для добавления `.appendChild, .insertBefore`. Изучите основы https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вопрос слишком общий, в ответе ограничусь примером:

```js
let container = document.createElement('div'); 
for (let el of Array.from(document.body.children))
  container.appendChild(el); 
document.body.appendChild(container); 

container.style.border = '2px dashed red';
```

```html
<header><h1>Header</h1></header>
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Когда необходимо получить все вложенные элементы, не обязательно использовать методы поиска в DOM - быстрее и надежнее обратиться к свойству `Node.children`, которое возвращает динамическую коллекцию элементов (типкаст к массиву в данном случае необходим как раз потому что коллекция "живая").

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение и пример